# About memory effect in E&M when E and B field has dependence in the history of E and B fields

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism

How should one define the memory effect in E&M formally? What is the physical way to visualize the memory effect? How should one understand it intuitively?

Comment: Are you referring to [this memory effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_effect)?

Comment: No. I mean in E&M if you have frequency spectrum of permitivity, the E & B field in the inverse fourier transform may depend upon the history of the past.

Comment: You should edit that information into the question! (comments are transient)

Comment: Will do it now.

Comment: formally "state memory" is incorporated into a theory/equation like this: $x(t_i) = f(t_i)+x(t_{i-1})$, this can be in *functional form*, *stochastic form* (Markov model), or *instantaneous/discrete form*, in think sth similar can be formulated for E/M fields

Comment: I would agree with Nikos on this one: a delay equation is a very good way to see the memory in linear systems without dispersion (otherwise one needs a complex integral, which is not so obvious). The proper physical formulation would be the Green's function approach, which basically defines a linear operator mapping the (time dependent) distribution of sources to the time dependent fields. I would have to defer to a sheer endless number of mathematical publications dealing with the serious difficulties in that approach, though.

Comment: Any good suggestion to emulate its behavior? I have no idea how to monte carlo out this behavior so far or seeing monte carlo will yield this sort of behavior.

Comment: @user45765 you have to define a valid initial state like Nikos shows with $x(t_{i−1})$ defined